# c# - Deserializing JSON array of integers and/or range of integeres

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I've searched "all over" the internet and can't find a solution to my problem.

I want to deserialize the following string

> {"retention": [
> { "kinds": [0, 1, [5, 7], [40, 49]], "time": 3600, "count": 10000 }
> ]}
>
> kinds[0] -> integer
> kinds[1] -> integer
> kinds[2] -> integer range

```
public class RelayRetention
{
public override string ToString()
    {
        string text = Environment.NewLine;

        return text;
    }

    //[JsonPropertyName("kinds")] public int[][]? KindsArrys { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("kinds")] public int[]? Kinds { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("time")] public int? Time { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("count")] public int? Count { get; set; }
}
```

```
string s = "{"retention": [
    { "kinds": [0, 1, [5, 7], [40, 49]], "time": 3600, "count": 10000 }";
]}
RelayRetention r = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RelayRetention>(s);
```

Comment: You will not be able to compile this code. Pls post the correct one

Comment: It might work with `public List<object> kinds { get; set; }`.

Comment: Hi @500-InternalServerError,

Comment: Hi @500-InternalServerError, Your suggestion works. thanks a lot.

Comment: And what means kinds[0] -> integer kinds[1] -> integer kinds[2] -> integer range  could you pls explain?

Comment: @Serge 
kinds[0] -> integer type 
kinds[1] -> integer type
kinds[2] -> integer range type

Comment: @redline Not everybody as smart . The range operator (..)

Comment: @Serge what do you mean with range operator (..) ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix your code and class

```
List<RelayRetention> lr =JsonObject.Parse(json)["retention"]
                                    .Deserialize<List<RelayRetention>>();
public class RelayRetention
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string text = Environment.NewLine;

        return text;
    }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("kinds")] public List<object>? Kinds { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("time")] public int? Time { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("count")] public int? Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i'm newby, sorry

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RelayRetention
{
    [JsonPropertyName("kinds")] public List<object>? Kinds { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("time")] public int? Time { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("count")] public int? Count { get; set; }
}

//kinds[0] -> integer type 
//kinds[1] -> integer type 
//kinds[2] -> integer range type
//kinds[3] -> integer range type

string str = "{[{\"kinds\": [0, 1, [5, 7], [40, 49]], \"time\": 3600, \"count\": 10000 }]}";
RelayRetention r = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RelayRetention>(str);
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with your question since a json sting  in the question  is completely different. This json string is not even valid. For the future test your answer if you ever will be able to create one.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**